# Posting to Facebook wall in python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I have some strange issue, which maybe doesn't relate to coding at all (in which case I apologize).

I'm trying to post on my facebook wall using python, and I use facepy library. Code looks like something like this:

```
graph = GraphAPI(access_token)

    graph.post(
        path='me/feed',
        message = message)
```

It posts a message on my wall, but this message is only visible for me. None of my friends can see this. I don't why is this, my app has public activity privacy and manually I can post messages that every one sees.

What can cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the privacy settings? 
Refer to the Facebook API on Privacy here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/privacy-parameter/

Specifically, you will want to use `privacy={'value':'EVERYONE'}` before posting.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that it should work, but it gives `OAuthError: [100] (#100) privacy must contain a valid privacy 'value'`.

Comment: Ok, I translated dictionary to json and it sent, but it's invisible. What the hell is goin' on?

Answer (score 0):

you should include the whole JSON string

`"privacy" = '{"value":"EVERYONE|SELF|...etc"}'`